# Merge Multi Array Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, merge

I have 3 arrays as follows:

```
"promotion_news_id" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "ID1"
    1 => "ID2"
    2 => "ID3"
  ]
```

```
  "promotion_news_name" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "abc 1"
    1 => "abc 2"
    2 => "abc 3"
  ]
```

```
  "news_id" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Title 1"
    1 => "Title 2
  ]
```

I want to combine those 3 arrays into 1 array as follows:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    'promotion_news_id' => "ID1"
    'promotion_news_name' => "abc 1"
    'news_id' => "Title 1"

  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    'promotion_news_id' => "ID2"
    'promotion_news_name' => "abc 2"
    'news_id' => "Title 2" 
  ],
  2 => array:3 [▼
    'promotion_news_id' => "ID3"
    'promotion_news_name' => "abc 3"
    'news_id' => "null"

  ]
]
```

I tried but failed to get a null value. 
Any help much appreciated! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing that all three of the array has the same number of elements,

```php
$result = [];
foreach($promotion_news_id as $index => $value){
    $result[] = array(
        'promotion_news_id' => $value
        'promotion_news_name' => $promotion_news_name[$index]
        'news_id' => $news_id[$index]
    )
}
```

Also, not sure why you have null value as `"null"` instead of `null`. The former is just a string, not an actual null value.

Comment: This working for me, the value is null, not "null", because I got it wrong. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `"null"` put `null`

Documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php)